# I keep getting segmentation fault 11?

Tags: c++, c++14

this is my code. I just need help figure out what went wrong in my program. I keep getting segmentation fault 11. I am guessing it is my deleteForm void function. PLease help and let me know what i did wrong.

here is the output. 
/usercode/script.sh: line 67:    89 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $output - < "/temp/inputFile"

```
t is : 
4
  2
    1
    3
  6
    5
t is : 
4
  2
    1
    3
  6
    5
t3 is : 
4
  2
    1
    3
  6
    5
    7
t2 is : 
4
  2
    1
    3
  6
    5
    8
      9
        11
t is : 
4
  2
    1
    3
  6
    5
t2 is : 
4
  2
    1
    3
  6
    5
      0
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


#include <cstdlib>   // necessary in order to use NULL

   `enter code here`class TreeNode
    {
     public:
    TreeNode() : left(NULL), right(NULL) {}

    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;
    int value;
};

class Tree
{
public:
    // Default constructor
    Tree();

    // Copy constructor
    Tree(const Tree& other);

    //Destructor
    ~Tree();

    // overloaded Assignment Operator
    Tree& operator=(const Tree& other);

    // Similar to insert function we discussed earlier
    // creates node and inserts it at appropriate position.
    void push(int value);

    // Returns the address of the node containing the value.
    TreeNode* find(int value) const;

    // Print the tree data
    void print() const;

    // Deletes the node with value in the tree and deallocates its memory.
    void deleteNode(int value);



private:
    // Root of the tree.
    TreeNode* start;

    //copyOther
    // you should implement and use this helper function inside your
    // copy constructor and overloadedAssignment operator.
    void copyOther(const Tree& other);

    // clear
    // you should implement and use this function inside your
    // destructor to delete all the nodes and free memory
    void clear();

    // pushFrom
    // Recursively push a single element into a tree.
    // Use it in your push function.
    void pushFrom(TreeNode* startingPoint, TreeNode* nodeToPush);

    // findFrom
    // Recursively find a single element in a tree.
    TreeNode* findFrom(TreeNode* startingPoint, int value) const;

    // printFrom
    //
    // Recursively print the values in a tree. Use
    // pre-order traversal.
    //
    // If a tree looks like this:
    //
    //           6
    //          /  \
    //         /    \
    //        5      8
    //       /      / \
    //      /      /   \
    //     0      7     9
    //
    // then it should be printed like this:
    //
    // 6
    //   5
    //     0
    //   8
    //     7
    //     9
    //
    //  Helper function that you should use inside your print function
    void printFrom(TreeNode* startintPoint, int numSpaces) const;

    // copyFrom
    // Recursively copy another tree's nodes. Use
    // pre-order traversal. Use this in CopyOther function.
    void copyFrom(TreeNode* startintPoint);

    // deleteFrom
    // should implement and use in the delete function.
    // Deletes the node with the value specified in the below function. 
    void deleteFrom(TreeNode* startintPoint, int value);

    // clearFrom
    // Recursively delete nodes. Use post-order traversal.
    // Use it in clear function.
    void clearFrom(TreeNode* startingPoint);
};



    //default constructor
     Tree::Tree()
     {
         start = NULL;
     }

       //copy constructor
    // must make the first node be nullpointer or copy constructor will never work!
       Tree::Tree(const Tree& other) :start(NULL)
     {
        //sent to private data
          copyOther(other);
       }

       //destructor
      Tree::~Tree()
       {
         clear();
      }

     // overloaded Assignment operator

        Tree& Tree::operator=(const Tree& other)
      {
       //check to see if they equal each other
       if (this != &other)
       {
            //delete last list
            clear();

        //copy the other list
        copyOther(other);

    }

    //returns pointer to object
    return *this;
}

         void Tree::push(int value)
        {
         //first create a new node like in bst example
           TreeNode* N1 = new TreeNode();
           N1->value = value;

       // if this is the first number, make it the root
        if (start == NULL)
       {
          start = N1;
          return;
        }

        //like insertNode, push value into tree with node and value
        pushFrom(start, N1);
   }

    TreeNode* Tree::find(int value)const
     {
      //implement the find from function
     return findFrom(start, value);
  }

       void Tree::print() const
{
    printFrom(start, 0);
}

     void Tree::deleteNode(int value)
{
    ///helper funciton of deleteFrom
    deleteFrom(start, value);
}


    void Tree::copyOther(const Tree& other)
{
    //send to private data
    copyFrom(other.start);
}

     void Tree::clear()
{
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    clearFrom(start);
}

          void Tree::pushFrom(TreeNode* startingPoint, TreeNode* nodeToPush)
       {
         if (startingPoint->value < nodeToPush->value)
          {
              //check to seee if the left side is empty
             if (startingPoint->right == NULL)
             {
                  startingPoint->right = nodeToPush;
           }
                else
               {
                //continue to traverse through the list
                  pushFrom(startingPoint->right, nodeToPush);
              }
          }
           else
             {
              if (startingPoint->left == NULL)
        {
            startingPoint->left = nodeToPush;
        }
        else
        {
            //continue to traverse through the list
            pushFrom(startingPoint->left, nodeToPush);
        }
    }
}

        TreeNode* Tree::findFrom(TreeNode* startingPoint, int value) const
{
    //check if list is empty
    if (startingPoint == NULL)
    {
        //cout << "That value does not exist. \n";
        return NULL;
    }

    //basecase
    if (startingPoint->value == value)
    {
        return startingPoint;
    }
    //recuriseve statments
    else if (value < startingPoint->value)
    {
        return findFrom(startingPoint->left, value);
    }
    else
    {
        return findFrom(startingPoint->right, value);
    }
}

      void Tree::printFrom(TreeNode* startintPoint, int numSpaces) const
{
    // basecase
    if (startintPoint == NULL)
    {
        return; // type void so we dont return anyting
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numSpaces; i++)
    {
        cout << " ";
    }

    cout << startintPoint->value << endl;

    numSpaces = numSpaces + 2;
    printFrom(startintPoint->left, numSpaces);
    printFrom(startintPoint->right, numSpaces);
}

      void Tree::copyFrom(TreeNode* startintPoint)
{
    if (startintPoint == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    push(startintPoint->value);
    copyFrom(startintPoint->left);
    copyFrom(startintPoint->right);
}

       void Tree::clearFrom(TreeNode* startingPoint)
{
    //check if its already empty
    if (startingPoint == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    clearFrom(startingPoint->left);
    clearFrom(startingPoint->right);

    // getting an error here as a 'signal SIGBARRT' but this is how the book deleted a treeptr
    delete startingPoint;
    start = NULL;
}



          void Tree::deleteFrom(TreeNode* startintPoint, int value)
{
    //from example in class, deleting a node

    if (startintPoint == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }
        else if (startintPoint->left != nullptr && value < startintPoint-
     >value)
    {

       deleteFrom(startintPoint->left, value);
    }
       else if (startintPoint->right != nullptr && value > startintPoint-
     >value)
    {
         deleteFrom(startintPoint->right, value);
    }
    else
    {
        if (startintPoint->left == nullptr && startintPoint->right == 
       nullptr)
        {
            delete startintPoint;
            startintPoint = nullptr;
        }
        else if (startintPoint->left == nullptr)
        {
            TreeNode* temp = startintPoint;
            startintPoint = startintPoint->right;
            delete temp;
        }
        else if (startintPoint->right == nullptr)
        {
            TreeNode* temp = startintPoint;
            startintPoint = startintPoint->left;
            delete temp;
        }
        else
        {
            TreeNode* temp = startintPoint->right;
            while (temp->left != NULL){
                temp = temp->left;

            }

            startintPoint->value = temp->value;
            deleteFrom(startintPoint->right, temp->value);



}
    }


}


int main()
{
    Tree t;

    t.push(4);
    t.push(2);
    t.push(1);
    t.push(3);
    t.push(6);
    t.push(5);

    cout<<"t is : "<<endl;
    t.print();


    Tree t3(t);
    t3.push(7);

    cout<<"t is : "<<endl;
    t.print();
    cout<<"t3 is : "<<endl;
    t3.print();

    Tree t2;
    t2.push(2);
    t2.push(1);
    t2.push(3);

    t2 = t;

    t2.push(8);
    t2.push(9);
    t2.push(11);

    cout<<"t2 is : "<<endl;
    t2.print();
    cout<<"t is : "<<endl;
    t.print();

    t2.deleteNode(1);
    t2.deleteNode(5);

    cout<<"t2 is : "<<endl;
    t2.print();

    TreeNode *node = t.find(5);
    cout << "found: " << node->value << endl;

    node = t.find(100000);
    cout << "t.find(100000): " << node << endl;
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here. Did you try using a debugger? Also you could follow more modern c++ practices and use `nullptr` rather than `NULL`. You could then dispense with `cstdlib`.

Comment: This is too large of a code dump. Please work on creating a [mcve]. Now is also an excellent time to learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: Should I rewrite the code

Comment: Problem is with you     t2.deleteNode(1);
    t2.deleteNode(5);

Comment: TreeNode* temp = startintPoint->right;
            while (temp->left != NULL){
                temp = temp->left;

            }

            startintPoint->value = temp->value;
            deleteFrom(startintPoint->right, temp->value);  This is not following the tree deletion principle

Comment: Please read [ask].  Good questions on stack overflow should attempt to isolate the issue being encountered into the smallest possible sample of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your updated working code ,you had problem in implementing delete function of tree.I have updated your delete function . Do clear your concept on [tree deletion](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Binary_search_tree/Removal)

**Three cases needs to be handled by delete function**

Your function was able to do 1 and 3 perfectly .2nd was not implemented correctly

***1. Node to be removed has no children***

***2.Node to be removed has one child.***

***3.Node to be removed has two children.***

```
#include <cstdlib>   // necessary in order to use NULL
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    


class TreeNode
{
public:
    TreeNode() : left(NULL), right(NULL) {}

    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;
    int value;
};

class Tree
{
public:
    // Default constructor
    Tree();

    // Copy constructor
    Tree(const Tree& other);

    //Destructor
    ~Tree();

    // overloaded Assignment Operator
    Tree& operator=(const Tree& other);

    // Similar to insert function we discussed earlier
    // creates node and inserts it at appropriate position.
    void push(int value);

    // Returns the address of the node containing the value.
    TreeNode* find(int value) const;

    // Print the tree data
    void print() const;

    // Deletes the node with value in the tree and deallocates its memory.
    void deleteNode(int value);



private:
    // Root of the tree.
    TreeNode* start;

    //copyOther
    // you should implement and use this helper function inside your
    // copy constructor and overloadedAssignment operator.
    void copyOther(const Tree& other);

    // clear
    // you should implement and use this function inside your
    // destructor to delete all the nodes and free memory
    void clear();

    // pushFrom
    // Recursively push a single element into a tree.
    // Use it in your push function.
    void pushFrom(TreeNode* startingPoint, TreeNode* nodeToPush);

    // findFrom
    // Recursively find a single element in a tree.
    TreeNode* findFrom(TreeNode* startingPoint, int value) const;

    // printFrom
    //
    // Recursively print the values in a tree. Use
    // pre-order traversal.
    //
    // If a tree looks like this:
    //
    //           6
    //          /  \
    //         /    \
    //        5      8
    //       /      / \
    //      /      /   \
    //     0      7     9
    //
    // then it should be printed like this:
    //
    // 6
    //   5
    //     0
    //   8
    //     7
    //     9
    //
    //  Helper function that you should use inside your print function
    void printFrom(TreeNode* startintPoint, int numSpaces) const;

    // copyFrom
    // Recursively copy another tree's nodes. Use
    // pre-order traversal. Use this in CopyOther function.
    void copyFrom(TreeNode* startintPoint);

    // deleteFrom
    // should implement and use in the delete function.
    // Deletes the node with the value specified in the below function.
    TreeNode* deleteFrom(TreeNode *root, int value);

    // clearFrom
    // Recursively delete nodes. Use post-order traversal.
    // Use it in clear function.
    void clearFrom(TreeNode* startingPoint);
};

TreeNode* FindMin(TreeNode* root){
    while(root->left != NULL) root = root->left;
    return root;
}


//default constructor
Tree::Tree()
{
    start = NULL;
}

//copy constructor
// must make the first node be nullpointer or copy constructor will never work!
Tree::Tree(const Tree& other) :start(NULL)
{
    //sent to private data
    copyOther(other);
}

//destructor
Tree::~Tree()
{
    clear();
}

// overloaded Assignment operator

Tree& Tree::operator=(const Tree& other)
{
    //check to see if they equal each other
    if (this != &other)
    {
        //delete last list
        clear();

        //copy the other list
        copyOther(other);

    }

    //returns pointer to object
    return *this;
}

void Tree::push(int value)
{
    //first create a new node like in bst example
    TreeNode* N1 = new TreeNode();
    N1->value = value;

    // if this is the first number, make it the root
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        start = N1;
        return;
    }

    //like insertNode, push value into tree with node and value
    pushFrom(start, N1);
}

TreeNode* Tree::find(int value)const
{
    //implement the find from function
    return findFrom(start, value);
}

void Tree::print() const
{
    printFrom(start, 0);
}

void Tree::deleteNode(int value)
{
    ///helper funciton of deleteFrom
    deleteFrom(start, value);
}


void Tree::copyOther(const Tree& other)
{
    //send to private data
    copyFrom(other.start);
}

void Tree::clear()
{
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    clearFrom(start);
}

void Tree::pushFrom(TreeNode* startingPoint, TreeNode* nodeToPush)
{
    if (startingPoint->value < nodeToPush->value)
    {
        //check to seee if the left side is empty
        if (startingPoint->right == NULL)
        {
            startingPoint->right = nodeToPush;
        }
        else
        {
            //continue to traverse through the list
            pushFrom(startingPoint->right, nodeToPush);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (startingPoint->left == NULL)
        {
            startingPoint->left = nodeToPush;
        }
        else
        {
            //continue to traverse through the list
            pushFrom(startingPoint->left, nodeToPush);
        }
    }
}

TreeNode* Tree::findFrom(TreeNode* startingPoint, int value) const
{
    //check if list is empty
    if (startingPoint == NULL)
    {
        //cout << "That value does not exist. \n";
        return NULL;
    }

    //basecase
    if (startingPoint->value == value)
    {
        return startingPoint;
    }
    //recuriseve statments
    else if (value < startingPoint->value)
    {
        return findFrom(startingPoint->left, value);
    }
    else
    {
        return findFrom(startingPoint->right, value);
    }
}

void Tree::printFrom(TreeNode* startintPoint, int numSpaces) const
{
    // basecase
    if (startintPoint == NULL)
    {
        return; // type void so we dont return anyting
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numSpaces; i++)
    {
        cout << " ";
    }

    cout << startintPoint->value << endl;

    numSpaces = numSpaces + 2;
    printFrom(startintPoint->left, numSpaces);
    printFrom(startintPoint->right, numSpaces);
}

void Tree::copyFrom(TreeNode* startintPoint)
{
    if (startintPoint == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    push(startintPoint->value);
    copyFrom(startintPoint->left);
    copyFrom(startintPoint->right);
}

void Tree::clearFrom(TreeNode* startingPoint)
{
    //check if its already empty
    if (startingPoint == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    clearFrom(startingPoint->left);
    clearFrom(startingPoint->right);

    // getting an error here as a 'signal SIGBARRT' but this is how the book deleted a treeptr
    delete startingPoint;
    start = NULL;
}


TreeNode* Tree::deleteFrom(TreeNode *root, int value){
    if(root == NULL) return root;
    else if(value < root->value) root->left = deleteFrom(root->left,value);
    else if(value > root->value) root->right = deleteFrom(root->right, value);
    else {
        // Case 1: No Child
        if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL){
            delete root;
            root = NULL;
            // Case 2: one child
        } else if(root->left == NULL){
            TreeNode *temp = root;
            root = root->right;
            delete temp;
        } else if(root->right == NULL){
            TreeNode *temp = root;
            root = root->left;
            delete temp;
        } else{
            TreeNode *temp = FindMin(root->right);
            root->value = temp->value;
            root->right = deleteFrom(root->right, temp->value);
        }
    }
    return root;
}




int main()
{
    Tree t;

    t.push(4);
    t.push(2);
    t.push(1);
    t.push(3);
    t.push(6);
    t.push(5);

    cout<<"t is : "<<endl;
    t.print();


    Tree t3(t);
    t3.push(7);

    cout<<"t is : "<<endl;
    t.print();
    cout<<"t3 is : "<<endl;
    t3.print();

    Tree t2;
    t2.push(2);
    t2.push(1);
    t2.push(3);

    t2 = t;

    t2.push(8);
    t2.push(9);
    t2.push(11);

    cout<<"t2 is : "<<endl;
    t2.print();
    cout<<"t is : "<<endl;
    t.print();

    t2.deleteNode(1);
    t2.deleteNode(5);

    cout<<"t2 is : "<<endl;
    t2.print();

    TreeNode *node = t.find(5);
    cout << "found: " << node->value << endl;

    node = t.find(100000);
    cout << "t.find(100000): " << node << endl;
}
```

Output

```
t is : 
4
  2
    1
    3
  6
    5
t is : 
4
  2
    1
    3
  6
    5
t3 is : 
4
  2
    1
    3
  6
    5
    7
t2 is : 
4
  2
    1
    3
  6
    5
    8
      9
        11
t is : 
4
  2
    1
    3
  6
    5
t2 is : 
4
  2
    3
  6
    8
      9
        11
found: 5
t.find(100000): 0x0
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: @PPT Took 30 min dude to find your deletion implementation was wrong

Comment: Code only answers tend to result in [Cargo Cult Programmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Recommend explaining what OP did wrong, why it was wrong, and why your solution fixed the problem.

Comment: else
        {
            TreeNode* temp = startintPoint->right;
            while (temp->left != NULL){
                temp = temp->left;

            }

            startintPoint->value = temp->value;
            deleteFrom(startintPoint->right, temp->value);  This just deletes node but doesn't link back

Comment: Sorry about that, for the answer, when I use TreeNode* Tree:: deleteFrom it works perfectly with no problem. My assignment was to use Void function, not TreeNode.